# very simple slide show with previous and next control

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a very simple slide show with some very basic controls such as previous and back. The next seems to be working fine but the previous is showing some issues. When I am hitting the previous the container is becoming completely blank for a while before an item shows up.How do I handle this? Here is what i have

```
<ul class="container">
    <li class="item">One</li>
    <li class="item">Two</li>
    <li class="item">Three</li>
</ul>

<div class="prev">Prev</div>
<div class="next">Next</div>
```

And here is the script

```
$('.item:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function () {
    $('.item').eq(0).hide()
        .next('.item').show()
        .end().appendTo('.container');
}, 3000);

$('.next').click(function(){
    $('.item:visible').hide().next().show()
    .end().appendTo('.container');
});

$('.prev').click(function(){
    $('.item:visible').hide().prev().show()
    .end().appendTo('.container');
});
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/arE2z/5/

Comment: @Alvaro--Thanks for the edit

Comment: I played with this for about 15 minutes and couldn't narrow down the issue. As a side note, the jQuery Cycle plugin is great for slideshows (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). You may want to take a look.

Comment: Maybe an idea. As your visible element as became the first of the list, prev() doesn't match any element. Maybe aiming for the last LI will be a part of the solution

Comment: Also, the Bootstrap carousel. I had a play around as well and I wasn't sure. You could try next/previousSibling in plain js too. To add to Eden, maybe saving a current to be used as your previous would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest structuring it a little better with an object, so that you have more control over the slideshow in the future?

Check out the live example here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FbPkK/3/)

The JS:

```
var slideShow = {
    i: 0,
    next: function() {
        this.i++;
        if(this.i === this.max()) {
            this.i = 0;
        };
        this.reset();
        this.goTo(this.i);
    },
    prev: function() {
        if(this.i === 0) {
            this.i = this.max();
        };
        this.i--;
        this.reset();
        this.goTo(this.i);
    },
    goTo: function(i) {
        $('.item').eq(i).addClass('active');
    },
    init: function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            slideShow.next();
        }, 3000);
    },
    reset: function() {
        $('.item').removeClass('active');
    },
    max: function() {
        return $('.item').length;
    }

};

slideShow.init();

$('.next').click(function(){
    slideShow.next();
});

$('.prev').click(function(){
    slideShow.prev();
});
```

The CSS:

```
.container{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:beige;
}
.item {
    display: none;
    font-size:60px;
    list-style:none;
}
.item.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @seth--this is great.

Comment: @soum, glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rearranging the elements I check instead if exists a next/prev element and if not handle that accordingly

```
$('.item').hide();
$('.item:eq(0)').show();
setInterval(function () {
    $('.next').click();
}, 3000);

$('.next').click(function(){
    var $visible = $('.item:visible'); 
    if ($visible.next().length) $visible.hide().next().show();
    else {
        $visible.hide();
        $('.item').first().show();
    }
});

$('.prev').click(function(){
    var $visible = $('.item:visible'); 
    if ($visible.prev().length) $visible.hide().prev().show();
    else {
        $visible.hide();
        $('.item').last().show();
    }
});
```

jsfiddle just died but this should work.
will show you the fiddle as soon as jsfiddle is back.

there fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/arE2z/14/

Comment: @Guy--Thanks for the direction. It makes sense. Yeah js fiddle just died.